# How to create a Terrain from a Picture/Map?

Tags: modeling

I started working with blender, because I wanted to create models and a map for a test game. However I am till date not able to create a terrain with blender using a picture 
The green part of this picture:

[image]

Is anyone here who knows good tutorials for this specific map or books or tips, I am a little frustrated working on this.

Comment: I can think of drawing the map from top view. The roads to be black and the peaks to be white and then use it as displacement map. Like this one https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heightmap

Comment: I dont know that much about heightmaps. I would know how to create peaks and roads, but I dont know how to create this valley, the slope is my problem. Could it  work, when using a gradient (black and white)?

Comment: Yes, gradient would be a slope in the displacement.

Comment: Is there any program, I could use? Using something like paint  would be too rough I guess

Comment: Gimp, photoshop probably

Comment: Hey, i figured out, that it is not a good idea for me to do anything, that has to do with drawing, someone could go blind. Do you maybe have other of these ideas

Comment: Reference image + proportional editing perhaps?